# Javascript regex .match() is null

Tags: javascript, regex

```
console.log(r.message); //returns "This transaction has been authorized"
if (r.message.match(/approved/).length > 0 || r.message.match(/authorized/).length > 0) {
// ^ throws the error: r.message.match(/approved/) is null
```

Is this not the correct way to do matching in JavaScript?

```
success: function (r) {
    $('.processing').addClass('hide');
    if (r.type == 'success') {
        console.log(r.message);
        if (r.message.match(/approved/).length > 0 || r.message.match(/authorized/).length > 0) {
            triggerNotification('check', 'Payment has been accepted');

            //document.location = '/store/order/view?hash='+r.hash;
        } else {
            triggerNotification('check', r.message);
        }
    } else {
        $('.button').show();

        var msg = 'Unable to run credit card: '+r.message;

        if (parseInt(r.code) > 0) {
            msg = msg+' (Error code: #'+r.code+')';
        }
        triggerNotification('x', msg);
    }
},
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since you are getting authorized message the statement `r.message.match(/approved/)` will return null and hence the issue.

Rewrite the check as follows:

```
if (/approved|authorized/.test(r.message)) {
```

Comment: +1 for using `test`, which is the correct way to approach this situation

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
if (r.message.match(/approved/) || r.message.match(/authorized/)) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .search() instead of .match() if you're using it in comparison to numbers.

### --> [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Shaz/YwAEk/3/) <--

Comment: Say, could you please tell me where I might find your example? ;o)

Comment: Uh yeah, that was actually sort of **`--> a joke <--`**. ;o)

Comment: I think I misread the code before, so don't mind my answer. :)